# How to make tf.data.Dataset.map function executed only once in first epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I try to implement some transformation on dataset by using tf.data.Dataset.

I found the transformation was executed in every epoch. Is it possible that the map function is executed in first epoch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use different datasets. That's easy in a custom training loop. Just like that:

```
def transformation(inputs, labels):
    tf.print('With transformation!')
    return inputs, labels

def no_transformation(inputs, labels):
    tf.print('No transformation!')
    return inputs, labels

data_with_transform = data.take(4).map(transformation).batch(4)
data_no_transform = data.take(4).map(no_transformation).batch(4)
```

And then later:

```
if epoch < 1:
    ds = data_with_transform
else:
    ds = data_no_transform

for X_train, y_train in ds:
    train_step(X_train, y_train)
```

Full example:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

data, info = tfds.load('iris', split='train', as_supervised=True,
                       with_info=True)

def transformation(inputs, labels):
    tf.print('With transformation!')
    return inputs, labels

def no_transformation(inputs, labels):
    tf.print('No transformation!')
    return inputs, labels

data_with_transform = data.take(4).map(transformation).batch(4)
data_no_transform = data.take(4).map(no_transformation).batch(4)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(info.features['label'].num_classes)
])

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
train_acc = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)


@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(inputs)
        loss = loss_object(labels, logits)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    train_loss(loss)
    train_acc(labels, logits)


def main(epochs=5):

    for epoch in range(epochs):

        train_loss.reset_states()
        train_acc.reset_states()

        if epoch < 1:
            ds = data_with_transform
        else:
            ds = data_no_transform

        for X_train, y_train in ds:
            train_step(X_train, y_train)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
With transformation!
With transformation!
With transformation!
With transformation!

No transformation!
No transformation!
No transformation!
No transformation!

No transformation!
No transformation!
No transformation!
No transformation!

No transformation!
No transformation!
No transformation!
No transformation!

No transformation!
No transformation!
No transformation!
No transformation!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's very helpful. I will follow this as guide.

Comment: I just read your solution carrfully. Maybe I didn't express clearly. What I want to implement is I want to directly use the transformation version obtained from map function executed in first epoch, instead of execute map function every epoch. Namely, you solution does not use the transformation generated during the first epoch.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to save the random transformations of the first epoch (i.e., the 100 random transformations of the 100 data points), and apply them to the next epoch (i.e., the 100 observations)?

Comment: Yes, do you have any idea? Anyway, still appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: Ok I actually have an answer to that. Maybe you could post a new question explaining it more concisely?

Comment: Please check the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057738/how-to-directly-use-the-trasformation-generated-by-map-function-in-first-epoch-i

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.data.Dataset.cache()` to limit `map()` to the first epoch. Call after any transformations you only want applied once, but before transformations you want applied every epoch.

For example:

```
ds = ds.map(lambda x, y: (my_first_epoch_only_transformation(x), y)).cache()
ds = ds.map(lambda x, y: (my_every_epoch_transformation(x), y))
```

From the [tf.data.Dataset.cache() docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#cache):

> Caches the elements in this dataset.
>
> The first time the dataset is iterated over, its elements will be
> cached either in the specified file or in memory. Subsequent
> iterations will use the cached data.