# How to directly use the transformation generated by map function in first epoch instead of executing map function every epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I want to apply some transformation to dataset by using map function. However, I found the map function was executed in every epoch.
Is it possible that the map function is only executed in first epoch and the following epochs directly use the transformation generated in first epoch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the seed with Tensorflow and apply transformations with `tf.image`, the random transformations will be consistent between epochs.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage import data
tf.random.set_seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def transform(image):
    image = tf.image.random_hue(image, 0.5, 1.)
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image)
    return image

X = tf.stack([data.chelsea() for i in range(4)])
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X).map(transform)

inputs = [[], []]

for epoch in range(2):
    for sample in ds:
        inputs[epoch].append(sample)

inputs_paired = [i for s in inputs for i in s]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.1, hspace=.1)
for i in range(8):
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 4, i + 1)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.imshow(inputs_paired[i])
plt.show()
```

Top is the first epoch, bottom is the second epoch.

[image]